# Accessing MeasureIt data with a script

Tags: python, scripting, measurement

I’d like to dimension and measure corner angles of objects with MeasureIt and then access them with a script so I can output a list of the objects with their specs. At this point I'd just like to know if it's possible before I go down that road. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: just asking for a friend if -- you've ever solved this?